# Distances precalculation for Optaplanner with Quarkus

Tags: quarkus, optaplanner

I want to solve the VRP problem (with some addition) with Optaplanner. In the documentation, it's often said, that it's a good thing to precalculate the distances between locations and then use a `map` for each location to get `distanceTo(location)`.

I use Optaplanner with Quarkus and I am wondering when and how to precalculate these traveling times +how to assign obtained `travelDistanceMap` to a specific location. I'd like to use Google maps for doing it.

Answer (score 1):

In [optaweb-vehicle-routing](https://github.com/kiegroup/optaweb-vehicle-routing), we use GraphHopper embedded, but to scale out it's better use either OSRM or a bulk distance matrix API like that of Google Maps or GraphHopper Enterprise.

See this video https://youtu.be/rEeAML74oWo